# On primes of the form $2\pi(n)p_n+1$, for some $n\geq 1$ being $\pi(x)$ the prime-counting function and $p_k$ the $k$th prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I was inspired in the sequence `A088348` from the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) to explore if there are primes of the form $$2\pi(n)p_n+1,\tag{1}$$
when $1\leq n$ runs over integers, where $\pi(x)$ denotes the prime-counting function and $p_n$ the $n$th prime number.

Previous sequence starts as $$7, 29, 67, 79, 137, 233, 311,\ldots\tag{2}$$

I think that this sequence isn't in the literature. I would like to define it and explore some properties if it is feasible.

**Claim.** The prime number theorem and the comparison test implies that $$\sum_{\substack{p\text{ primes of the form }\\2\pi(n)p_n+1}\\\quad\text{ for some }n\geq 1}\frac{1}{p}\tag{3}$$
is convergent.

> **Question.** Is it known or in case that this sequence isn't in the literature, if our sequence has infinitely many terms (if there are infinitely many primes of the form $(1)$)? Can you propose as a conjecture how many terms less than $x$ should have our sequence $(1)$, for $x$ sufficiently large (I am asking if you can propose what is/a statement about the asymptotic behaviour of the counting function $\pi(x)$ of our sequence $(1)$ you can work on assuption of the conditions that you need)? **Many thanks.**

If our sequence and previous questions is well-knowns please answer this question as a reference request.

Comment: Have you tried running code and seeing if there is any logarithmic progression to the number of primes of this form less than x?

Comment: No, in fact I never did such test to know if a sequence seems a logarithmic progression @SeanNemetz Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: It's an interesting question to say the least. Mathematicians don't even know if there are infinitely many primes of the form $2p+1$, where $p$ is prime.

Comment: Many thanks @SeanNemetz

Comment: Good Luck on the problem

Answer (score 1):

**Just an observation to the claim (3)**. Long time ago I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/is-there-a-way-to-show-that-sqrtp-n-n) leading to $\pi(x)>\sqrt{x}$ from some $x$ onwards. And $p_n>n$, so $2\pi(n)p_n+1 > 2n\sqrt{n}$ from some $n_0$ onwars. As a result
$$\sum_{\substack{p\text{ primes of the form }\\2\pi(n)p_n+1}\\\quad\text{ for some }n\geq 1}\frac{1}{p}<\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{1}{2\pi(n)p_n+1}< \sum\limits_{n=1}^{n_0-1}\frac{1}{2\pi(n)p_n+1} + \sum\limits_{n=n_0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n^{1+\frac{1}{2}}}$$
which [indeed converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#p-series).

Comment: Many thanks for your nice proof and feedback. I am going to read your reasoning.