# Show that $p_n^{1-\epsilon}\le n$ using PNT

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Assuming PNT $$\pi(x)\sim \frac{x}{\log{x}}$$
How can we show that given any $\epsilon>0$ $$p_n^{1-\epsilon}< n,$$ for all sufficiently large $n$ ($p_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ prime.)

My work:
Setting $x=p_n$ we get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n\log{p_n}}{p_n}=1\Rightarrow 1-\epsilon<\dfrac{n\log{p_n}}{p_n}$, for sufficiently large $n$. Now if I can show that $$\dfrac{n\log{p_n}}{p_n}\le\dfrac{\log n}{\log{p_n}}$$
then the result follows. But I am unable to show the last inequality.

Can someone please help with this? Other approaches are welcome as well.
[NOTE: Using this I want to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log{n}}{\log{p_n}}=1$ so please don't use that, although it can be derived independently]

Thank you

Comment: To be more precise, $\implies 1-\epsilon<\frac{n\log p_n}{p_n}$ fot sufficiently large $n.$

Comment: It works for $\varepsilon \geq \frac{1}{2}$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/is-there-a-way-to-show-that-sqrtp-n-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\color{red}{\text{1. One way}}$

I will use 2 results

- [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)
  $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\pi(n)\ln{(n)}}{n}=1 \Rightarrow
  \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{\pi(n)\ln{(n)}}=1 \tag{1}$$
- [and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number)
  $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{p_n}{n\ln{(n)}}=1 \tag{2}$$

> **Proposition 1.1** $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\ln{(n)}}{\ln{(p_n)}}=1$$

$\{p_n\}$ is a subsequence of $\{n\}$, thus, from $(1)$, 
$$\lim\limits_{p_n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\pi(p_n)\ln{(p_n)}}{p_n}=1 \Rightarrow 
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\pi(p_n)\ln{(p_n)}}{p_n}=1 \Rightarrow ...$$
because $\pi(p_n)=n$
$$...\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n\ln{(p_n)}}{p_n}=1 \tag{3}$$
Now
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\ln{(n)}}{\ln{(p_n)}}=
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{n\ln{(n)}}{p_n}\cdot\frac{p_n}{n\ln{(p_n)}}\right)=\\
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{n\ln{(n)}}{p_n}\right)\cdot \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{p_n}{n\ln{(p_n)}}\right)\overset{(2)(3)}{=}1$$

> **Proposition 1.2** For large enough $n$  $$p_n^{1-\varepsilon}<n$$

From 
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\ln{(n)}}{\ln{(p_n)}}=1$$
using the definition of limit, $\forall\varepsilon >0, \exists N(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n> N(\varepsilon)$
$$\left|\frac{\ln{(n)}}{\ln{(p_n)}}-1\right|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow
1-\varepsilon <\frac{\ln{(n)}}{\ln{(p_n)}}< 1+\varepsilon \Rightarrow \\
(1-\varepsilon)\ln{(p_n)} <\ln{(n)}< (1+\varepsilon)\ln{(p_n)} \Rightarrow \\
\ln{(p_n)^{(1-\varepsilon)}} <\ln{(n)}< \ln{(p_n)^{(1+\varepsilon)}} \Rightarrow ...$$
$e^x$ is ascendng, thus
$$... p_n^{1-\varepsilon} <n< p_n^{1+\varepsilon} $$

---

$\color{red}{\text{2. Another way}}$

Using [Vallée-Poussin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function), for large enough $x$
$$\pi(x)>\frac{x}{\ln(x)-(1-\varepsilon)}>\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$$
Let's show that for large enough $x$ we also have 
$$\frac{x}{\ln(x)}>x^{1-\varepsilon}$$
which is the same as showing $$\frac{x^{\varepsilon}}{\ln{x}}>1$$
for large $x>0$.

> **Propositions 2.1** Function $f(x)=\frac{x^{\varepsilon}}{\ln{x}}$ is ascending for large $x>0$.

Because
$$f'(x)=\frac{x^{\varepsilon-1} (\varepsilon \ln{x}-1)}{\ln^2{x}}>0 \iff 
\varepsilon \ln{x}-1>0 \Rightarrow 
x> e^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}$$

> **Propositions 2.2** $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x) \rightarrow \infty$

If we assume it is bounded by a large $\alpha>0, \forall x>1$ and we know $\ln{x}$ is ascending
$$\frac{x^{\varepsilon}}{\ln{x}} < \alpha \iff 
1<x^{\varepsilon}< \alpha \ln{x} \iff 
\color{red}{0}<\varepsilon<\frac{\ln{\alpha}}{\ln{x}}+\frac{\ln{\ln{x}}}{\ln{x}}\rightarrow \color{red}{0}, x\rightarrow\infty$$
which is a contradiction.

So, for large $x$ we have 
$$\pi(x)>x^{1-\varepsilon}$$
which means, for large $n$ we have
$$n=\pi(p_n)>p_n^{1-\varepsilon}$$

Comment: Well I already mentioned in the note that I am trying to derive $\log n\sim \log{p_n}$ using my question (and later on to show that $p_n\sim n\log n$).

Comment: You also mentioned "Other approaches are welcome as well.". You can also use Vallée Poussin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function

Comment: Well of course the effort is appreciated, thanks for help.

Comment: @Vulthuryol is it better now?

Comment: how does the PNT implies vallee-poussin's inequality? Can you link a proof?

Comment: It's vice versa in fact. Vallée-Poussin was among the first to prove PNT.

Comment: From ${\frac {x}{\log x-(1-\varepsilon )}}<\pi(x)<{\frac {x}{\log x-(1+\varepsilon )}}$ it's easy to see ${\frac {1}{1-\frac{(1-\varepsilon )}{\log x}}}<\frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x}<{\frac {1}{1-\frac{(1+\varepsilon )}{\log x}}}$

Comment: I see how this implies PNT, but I am asking about the other way around. I mean my question is to assume PNT then derive this inequality.

Comment: PNT is not the best way to approximate $\pi(x)$, I don't know if the other way around is possible at all, using just PNT.