# Limit of a sequence where $U_n = \frac{(\log n )^p}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

What is the limit of this sequence where , $U_n = \frac{(\log n )^p}{n}$ where $p \ge  0$.

I have done this problem when $p$ is an integer.
Sorry but I am not too much familiar with writing questions in stack exchange.

Comment: See if you can exploit propositions 2.1 and 2.2 from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830029/show-that-p-n1-epsilon-le-n-using-pnt/2830189#2830189)

Comment: If you know the results for $p \in \mathbb N$, note that for general $p$, there is a $k\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $k \leqslant p<k+1$, and to get the limit, try the squeezing theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{(\log n )^p}{n}=e^{p\log(\log n)-\log n} \to 0$$

indeed

$$p\log(\log n)-\log n=\log n\left(p\frac{\log(\log n)}{\log n}-1\right)\to -\infty$$

since

$$\frac{\log(\log n)}{\log n} \to 0$$

which can be easily proved by $\frac{\log x}x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ by $x=\log y$ and $y \to \infty$.

Comment: Can we write $lim$ $x tends to infinity$ $f(n)g(n)$ = $lim$ $x tends to infinity$  $f(n)$ × $lim$ $x tends to infinity$ $g(n)$. When one of the sequence diverges? I don't know...

Comment: Note that here we are using something different that is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)=\lim_{n\to \infty} g(n)\cdot h(n)$$ and using the fact that $g(n)\to \infty$ and $h(n)\to -1$ and that’s leads to a not indeterminate form.