# For any positive integer $n$, show that $x\gg 1 \rightarrow \log{x} < \sqrt[n]{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

For any positive integer $n$, show that $x\gg 1 \rightarrow \log{x} < \sqrt[n]{x}$

I approached this problem by showing that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log{x}}{\sqrt[n]{x}}= 0$

I tried to show that the limit converges to zero by showing that the integral test, $$\int_{1}^{\infty}{\log{x}\over\sqrt[n]{x}} dx $$ converges, which would in turn mean that the limit converges to zero (due to the $n^{\text{th}}$-term test)

But I can't get how to solve this improper integral, and also don't know whether my approach is right in the first place.

Comment: Also, [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080038/calculate-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac-lnxxa-where-a-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

By L'Hopital's rule $\lim \frac {\log \, x} {\sqrt [n] {x}}=\lim \frac {1/x} {\frac 1 n x^{\frac 1 n -1}}=\lim \frac n {x^{\frac 1 n}}=0$.

Comment: oh my I missed that one. What if I just went with the integral test? How would I solve that improper integral?

Comment: Integral cannot be used here. Mere existence of $\int_1^{\infty} f(x)dx$ does  not guarantee that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mother of all inequalities abouzt the exponential,
$$ e^t\ge 1+t,$$
and multiplicativity, we find that for $y>(n+1)^{n+1}$,
$$ e^y=\left(e^{\frac y{n+1}}\right)^{n+1}\ge \left(1+\frac y{n+1}\right)^{n+1}>\frac{y^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}>y^n,$$
or:
$$ \sqrt[n]{e^x}>y.$$
Hence for $x>e^{(n+1)^{n+1}}$, we have (setting $y=\ln x$) 
$$\sqrt[n]x>\ln x.$$