# Evaluate the limit: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_a n!}{n^b},\ n\in\Bbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate the limit: 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_a n!}{n^b}, \ \ n\in\Bbb N
> $$

I've tried to consider two cases: $b < 0$, $b \ge 0$. First $b < 0$. This case is simple since the limit becomes:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_a n!}{n^b} = \lim_{n\to\infty}n^{|b|}\log_a n! = +\infty
$$

Now consider the case when $b \ge 0$, then we may apply Cesaro-Stolz theorem, then the limit is equal to the following limit:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log_a n!}{n^b} &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log_a (n+1)! - \log_an!}{(n+1)^b - n^b} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log_a(n+1)}{(n+1)^b - n^b}
\end{align}
$$

I've shown earlier that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((n+1)^b - n^b\right) = 0,\ \text{if}\ b\in(0, 1)\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((n+1)^b - n^b\right) = +\infty,\ \text{if}\ b > 1\\
$$

For $b = 1$ the limit becomes:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\log_an!\over n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\log_a\sqrt[n]{n!} = +\infty
$$

So it looks like:
$$
b \le 1 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_a n!}{n^b} = +\infty
$$

Here I'm not sure how to handle the case for $b > 1$. What are the steps to handle the case for $b > 1$? I know the limit is $0$, but want to justify that.

Comment: $log n! \sim n \log n$, so you get limit $0$ when $b>1$.  So far, you have not completed the case $b=1$.

Comment: If you vote down, please provide a reason for that, otherwise, it's not clear what's wrong with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For $b>1$**, use [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) for $f(x)=x^b$, i.e. $\exists c\in(n,n+1)$ and $n>0$ s.t.
$$(n+1)^b - n^b=bc^{b-1} \Rightarrow \\
b(n+1)^{b-1}>(n+1)^b - n^b > bn^{b-1}$$
and from some $n$ onwards, assuming $\ln{a}>0$:
$$0<\frac{\log_a(n+1)}{b(n+1)^{b-1}}=
\frac{\ln(n+1)}{b(n+1)^{b-1}\ln{a}} < 
\frac{\log_a(n+1)}{(n+1)^b - n^b} < 
\frac{\log_a(n+1)}{bn^{b-1}}=
\frac{\ln(n+1)}{bn^{b-1}\ln{a}}$$
because $b-1>0$, RHS goes to $0$ and by squeezing, the limit is $0$. There are quite a few proofs for RHS going to $0$, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830029/show-that-p-n1-epsilon-le-n-using-pnt/2830189#2830189) (*proposition 2.2*) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857391/how-can-i-prove-that-logkn-on-epsilon/2857420#2857420) (*proposition 2*).

For $\ln{a}<0$ we have
$$0>\frac{\ln(n+1)}{b(n+1)^{b-1}\ln{a}}> 
\frac{\log_a(n+1)}{(n+1)^b - n^b} > 
\frac{\ln(n+1)}{bn^{b-1}\ln{a}}$$
we the same result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use Stirling approximation.