# There are more primes than square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Will someone please help me in understanding the claims of corollary $2$ and $3$?

I understand that corollary $2$ means for large $N$ there are more primes than squares in the interval $[1,N]$ which can also be seen alternatively using Prime Number Theorem. But I want to understand it from the Claim made in this corollary by Euler.

I know the proof given here is wrong and lacks rigor. Actually this proof was given by Euler. Can we anyway reach to corollary by bypassing the wrong proof ?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: @PeterForeman: I think this is an extract of a translation of a work of Euler, and so you shouldn't judge it by 21st century standards. I wish I was able to contribute to mathematics $10^{-6}$ of what Euler did.

Comment: No..it is not in terms of bijection, it is rather in terms of density. I am aware of that proof using prime number theorem. I was just curious whether we could also prove that using the corollary.

Comment: Exactly @Rob Arthan

Comment: @PeterForeman Euler did this all the time, I remember reading about it in an MAA article about the Goldbach-Euler theorem (where he also used this method)

Comment: @PeterForeman - maybe the question could be considered in the context of *asymptotic density*, in which case they both are 0

Comment: Really the enormous development Euler did with minimum tools available at that time is worth appreciating.

Comment: Haha  fixed. @Rob Arthan

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now. Apparently, "câlin" is French for cuddle, but I think Euler's theory of cuddles is elsewhere in his collected works $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Between $1..N$ there are $\pi(N)$ primes and $\sqrt{N}$ squares and $\pi(N)>\sqrt{N}$, quite a few details are provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/is-there-a-way-to-show-that-sqrtp-n-n).

Comment: Yeah..I was also referring to the same @rytbase

Comment: One simple approach is still an open problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture