# Prime number logic

Tags: logic, prime-numbers

> It is conjectured that for every intever $n\geq1$ there is a prime $p$ with $n^2<p<(n+1)^2$.  Show that if this conjecture is true then $\pi(x)\geq\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor$ for all $x\geq2$.

I understand that the conjecture is true since in every interval there must be a prime in between. And I understand that $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes less than $x$ with $x\geq2$. I am just very confused on how to setup the proof to get the desired result. Can anyone give me a hint into the direction??

Comment: What's the source of this question?

Comment: The conjecture is open. The exercise is to show that it implies the given inequality.

Comment: Your reasoning does not show that the conjecture must be true. Not every interval in the natural numbers contains a prime.

Comment: Sorry I am not focusing on the conjecture, more on how to use the conjecture to prove the statement. I have spent 4 days on this proof and cannot get the desired result and was simply hoping someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: Assuming the conjecture, there's a prime in the interval $(1,4)$ another in the interval $(4,9)$, yet another in the interval $(9,16)$, and so on.  How many such intervals are there that are $\leq x$?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the conjecture is not obvious which you seem to believe , but remained unproven until today. Of course, for the exercise we do not need that the conjecture is actually true.

Comment: @Peter: It was proved today?!

Comment: @BrianTung Oops, I used an unlucky formulation :)

Comment: Ahh, yes, that is a common English bugaboo: "...but remains unproved **to the present day**" or something like that is a better formulation. :-)

Comment: That'd be pretty big news.

Comment: Some of the comments above and Robert Israel's answer seem to construe everything about the posted question literally, despite evidence of some confusion's in the poster's mind.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: At least one prime from $1^2$ to $2^2$, at least one from $2^2$ to $3^2$, ..., at least one from $(m-1)^2$ to $m^2$.  How many is that?

Comment: You only get $m-1<m$ primes.

Comment: I am sorry I just don't understand where the x comes into play here??

Comment: @JCAA There are two primes from $1^2$ to $2^2$, so that takes care of the extra $1$.

Comment: Yes, you can apply the conjecture starting with $2$. I did it starting with $3$ to be of the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

4 primes between 1 and 9 plus at least one prime between
every $t^2$ and $(t+1)^2$ for every $3\le t\le \lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor-1$. Altogether gives you $>\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$ primes smaller than $x$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the inequality?

Comment: Which inequality?

Comment: I fixed the answer replacing 4 by 9.

Comment: Why are you comparing between 1 and 9 since it should only be between n and n+1 which would actually be 1 and 4 for the first interval correct? And I am confused how you set up the inequality...

Comment: If you start with $1^2$ and not $3^2$ you will  get fewer than needed primes. What inequality did I set up?

Comment: 3 <= t <= floor(sqrt(x)) - 1

Comment: I start applying the fact from your question with $n=3$ (before ]$3^2$ there are 4 primes), hence $3\le t$. I stop counting when $(t+1)^2>x$, hence the upper bound. The number of applications of the fact is $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor - 1-2$. So altogether the number of primes $\le x$ is at least $4+\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor - 1-2=\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor +1$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a general remark, [in fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/206822/22583) $\pi(x)>\frac{x}{\ln{x}}>\sqrt{x}$ holds without assuming the conjecture. But let's use it, i.e. [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) to prove the inequality.

---

> **P1.** [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) $\iff \pi\left((n+1)^2\right)-\pi\left(n^2\right)\geq 1$ for any integer $n\geq 1$

It's obvious.

If $\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)-\pi\left(n^2\right)\geq 1$, then $\{1,2,...,(n+1)^2\}$ contains more primes than $\{1,2,...,n^2\}$. Thus, there is at least one prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.

If there is at least one prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$, then $\{1,2,...,(n+1)^2\}$ contains more primes than $\{1,2,...,n^2\}$. Thus $\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)-\pi\left(n^2\right)\geq 1$.

---

> **P2.** $\pi(n^2)\geq n$, for any integer $n\geq 2$.

By induction:

- it's true for $\pi(2^2)=2\geq 2$.
- from the induction hypotheses $\pi(n^2)\geq n$ we have $$\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)=\pi\left((n+1)^2\right)-\pi\left(n^2\right)+\pi\left(n^2\right)\overset{P1}{\geq} 
  1+\pi\left(n^2\right)\geq 
  1+n$$

---

Finally for all $x\geq2$
$$\pi\left(x\right)\geq \pi\left(\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor^2\right)\overset{P2}{\geq}\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor$$

simply because

- $\pi(x)$ is ascending ($x\geq y \Rightarrow \pi(x)\geq \pi(y)$) and
- $x\geq \lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor^2$ for $x\geq 0$, from $$\sqrt{x}=\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor + \{x\}\Rightarrow
  x = \lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor^2 + 2 \lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor \{x\} +\{x\}^2 \geq \lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor^2$$